# How to highlight a autocomplete list using the the Up key and the Down key (Ember.js)

Tags: javascript, jquery, ember.js

I have a auto complete and i will like to go thru the list using the up and down key to be able to highlighted here it is a example that how I want to be able to work http://jsfiddle.net/YnpW3/2/. I created a auto complete jsbin for the purpose http://jsbin.com/xezowozutu/1/edit?html,css,js,output

```
App.AutocompleteController = Ember.Controller.extend({
  searchText: null,
     searchResults: function() {
        var searchText = this.get('searchText');
        if (!searchText) { return; }

        var regex = new RegExp(searchText, 'i');
        return ['one', 'two', 'three'].filter(function(name) {
          return name.match(regex);
        });
      }.property('searchText')
    });
```